# Using awk to 'average' 2 data files

Tags: bash, awk

Say I have 2 data files dat1.txt

```
1 1
2 2
```

And dat2.txt

```
2 2
3 3
```

How can I use awk to "average" these files and save this to a new file?
So in this case I want output of a file dat3.txt:

```
1.5 1.5
2.5 2.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk one-liner should work:

```
awk '{n=NF/2;for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       printf "%.1f%s",($i+$(n+i))/2,i==n?RS:FS}' <(paste f1 f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, this supports more than two files too, you can input files like `myfiles*.txt`

**Input**

```
$ cat f1.txt
1 1
2 2

$ cat f2.txt
2 2
3 3
```

**Script**

```
  awk '
    FNR==1{ 
              nf++
              nc = NF 
          }
          { 
           for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) 
                 s[FNR,i] += $i;
                if (FNR > mnr) mnr = FNR
          }
     END {
           for (i = 1; i <= mnr; i++)
           {
             for (c=1; c <= nc; c++)
                  printf("%s%f", (c>1?OFS:""), s[i,c]/nf);
             printf "\n"
           }
         }
      ' f1.txt f2.txt                        # you can also input f*.txt
```

**Output**

```
1.500000 1.500000
2.500000 2.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)Sum[FNR"-"i]+=$i}
     END {
        for(l=1;l<=NR;l++){
           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf( "%2.1f ", Sum[l"-"i]/NR)
           printf( "\n")
           }
        }' dat.1 dat.2
```

Assuming both file have the same number of line and argument

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{a[FNR]+=$1; b[FNR]+=$2}END{for(;++i<=FNR;) print a[i]/(ARGC-1), b[i]/(ARGC-1)}' f1 f2
1.5 1.5
2.5 2.5
```

Explained:

```
{
    a[FNR]+=$1                             # sum col values into arrays
    b[FNR]+=$2                             # array for each field
}
END {
    for(;++i<=FNR;)                        # iterate arrays in ascending order
        print a[i]/(ARGC-1), b[i]/(ARGC-1) # and print array contents divided by filecount
}
```